# can't open .exe after made an app with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have two different problems with my Python script:

1. I made a simple design with the qt designer and converted it to an .py file. After I run the application in spyder, everything is working fine, but if I close the application, my console is still running and will not close again. I have to restart my console. How can I avoid this?
2. I converted the .py file to an .exe file with "pyinstaller". If I double click the exe, it will not open and I have no error message. I used the normal command "pyinstaller – onefile -w test.py". I am using Python 3.9 and Spyder as IDE.

This is my code. The code is directly generated from the command "pyuic5 -x test.ui -o test.py".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 720)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1280, 720))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.centralwidget.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_ProcessParameters = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.tab_ProcessParameters.setFont(font)
        self.tab_ProcessParameters.setObjectName("tab_ProcessParameters")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_ProcessParameters)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.frame_background = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_ProcessParameters)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.frame_background.setFont(font)
        self.frame_background.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(170, 170, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"border-radius: 20px;")
        self.frame_background.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_background.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_background.setObjectName("frame_background")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_background)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_background, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_ProcessParameters, "")
        self.tab_Visualization = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_Visualization.setObjectName("tab_Visualization")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_Visualization)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.frame_2_background = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_Visualization)
        self.frame_2_background.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(170, 170, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"border-radius: 20px;")
        self.frame_2_background.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2_background.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2_background.setObjectName("frame_2_background")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_2_background, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_Visualization, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1280, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Test"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_ProcessParameters), _translate("MainWindow", "Process Parameters"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_Visualization), _translate("MainWindow", "Visualization"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: run .exe manually in console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell to see error message. When you click then it may display error message very fast and you may not see it.

Comment: You enabled the windowed option so you may not get any error messages. As @furas suggested, it probably will show error message in the terminal. But if it doesnt, make the exe again without the `-w` and then run the exe from terminal

Answer (score 2):

The reason you dont have any error is you used `-w`. This will hide the the error message. If you want to see the error message first type without -w and see what is the error. And dont use `--onefile` it is usually problematic. And are you opening the app from build folder? Because if you are the app will not work. Open the app from dist folder.

use this command-
`pyinstaller filname.py`(this will show you the error.(run it from the terminal))
and then open it from dist folder. If there is no error then you can try-
`pyinstaller filname.py -w` to hide the terminal.